Issues with Contacts being exported accurately
I'm having issues when exporting contacts, and the changes I made in their accounts are not reflected in the output.
For example, I have a Mr. & Mrs. John Doe.  Then Mrs. John Doe passes away and I change it to only Mr. John Doe.  Yet when I go to export for a mailing Mr. & Mrs. John Doe is still exported although deleted months ago.  How can I keep this from happening?  Please be specific.  Thanks!
Mark

Check the "postal greeting" field in the communication prefs section of the contact record is getting updated properly. It should when you edit the contact but maybe it is getting an error. You can also run this scheduled job: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_update_greeting
